# Return const char** from immutable string

Tags: c, pointers, string-literals

I want to set return a `const char*` into `char**`
I want the compiler to validate there is no change on that `char*`.

What the correct syntax should look like?

```
const char* str = "some str";
void test(char const **out_str) {
    *out_str = str;
}
```

EDIT:

Maybe something like that?

```
char* const str = "some str";
void test(char** const out_str) {
    *out_str = str;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you intend to call this function, passing a `char**` to it ? And then expect the compiler to know that in *fact* it's a `const char**` ? Or am I misunderstanding your intent ? Can you clarify how you intend to call this, and where you would like this "compiler validation" to happen ?

Comment: While literal strings in C are not constant (i.e. you can have a `char *` variable point to a string literal) they are still read-only. Therefore it's recommended to always use `const char *` for string literals. That also means your wanted use of `char *` for pointing to a string literal is suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be called.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( char const **out_str ) 
{
    const char *str = "some str";
    *out_str = str;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *p;

    test( &p );

    puts( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
some str
```

String literals have static storage duration. So the code is valid.

As for this declaration `char** const` then it denotes a constant pointer to a pointer to char.